# How to use gaussian kernel in satellite imagery to change resolution of images

Tags: python, opencv

I want to change the `resolution(GSD)` of the `satellite images` using `Gaussian kernel`(gaussian blur in opencv_python). I have an image whose resolution is `15cm`
and I want to convert to `30cm,50cm,1m,1.20m,1.5m,2m`.
So to do this how can I use this gaussian filter to change the resolutions
or is there any methods to do this in python.
sample images is attached with this question

[Sample image press here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbYej.png)  
[___Description image of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6BQA.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example image? Perhaps you can get the effect you want by scaling your image. Try this example: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#scaling

Comment: You want to resize a given image at various levels ?

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 1000x1000 pixel image at 15cm resolution, and you want to know what it would look like at 30cm resolution, just use OpenCV's `cv2.resize()` or PIL/Pillow's `Image.resize()` to make it 500x500 pixels.

[OpenCV resize docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)

[PIL/Pillow resize docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html/)

You may subsequently elect to resize back up to 1000x1000 so images are of comparable size.